# How to make modals which have routes like Trello in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data, ember-router

I want to know how we can make modals which have routes.

In Trello, whenever you click on a card, the route changes from `abc.com/b/personal` to `abc.com/c/some-random-string` and the card opens in a modal. Also, when you close the modal, you get redirected to the previous url (`abc.com/b/personal`).

I want to know how can we achieve this using Emberjs.

Example: https://trello.com/b/ezWgKsol/sales-enterprise-feature-requests-sample

Comment: In the same way as all subroutes in ember. Template for subroute keep markup for opened modal. On close you just make transition into index route

Comment: *modal* in web land usually means just having a big, fixed size div with grey transparent background hanging over your page.

Comment: see this board (https://trello.com/b/ezWgKsol/sales-enterprise-feature-requests-sample) as an example of what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modal (using foundation) where we delete a record:

```
<div class="reveal" id="deleteLocationModal" data-reveal>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns">
            Are you sure you want to delete this location?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns">
            <button id="cancelButton" class="secondary button" data-close type="button">Cancel</button>
            <button id="deleteButton" class="button" {{action "deleteLocation" model}} data-close type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The router has the falling in the actions hash:

```
actions: {
    deleteLocation(model) {
        Ember.assert("Params must be provided", model);
        model.save().then(( /* response */ ) => {
            this.transitionTo('locations'); //locations is my index page.
            //flash message to inform the user of success.
        });
    }, (error) => {
        //handle error.
        //  display flash message
        //  rollback any dirty attributes

    });
}
```

I hope this helps,

Jeff

Comment: how will this open in a new route?

Comment: After the save takes place, the user is transitioned to a route.  In the example above I route them to locations which in my case is the index page for my app.   Modal closes and the page is updated.

Comment: what i want is that on clicking, the modal will open in a new route and then on closing the modal, he will be redirected to the previous route much like how Trello works. see this example: https://trello.com/b/ezWgKsol/sales-enterprise-feature-requests-sample. click on any of the cards.

Comment: Opening a modal in my case doesn't open a new route.   Sounds like in your use case you need to access a different model thus the need to open a new route?